# Dispatching Tasks periodically from a List FreeRTOS

Tags: operating-system, embedded, scheduled-tasks, dispatcher, freertos

I am using FreeRTOS to dispatch task set of 4 periodical tasks.
All tasks have the same period of 10 time units, but they differ in their release times. Release times are 10,3,5,0 time units for tasks T1,T2,T3,T4 respectively. All 4 tasks are stored inside the linked list `gll_t* pTaskList`. Tasks should run e.g.,
t=0 T4 is released, t=3 T2 is released, t=5 T3 is released, t=10 T1 is relased and T4 is executed again since it was released at t = 0, and so on...

However I have two problems with my dispatcher code:

**1. Problem** At t=0, only T4 is ready, but note that T1 has release time at 10, According to my if statement for T1 I have `0 % (10 + 10) == 0` , and T1 gets released even though it's not ready. I could introduce a boolean that tells whether a task has been released, but is there a smarter way to do it without introducing extra variables?

**2. Problem** At t=26, no tasks are ready, however, task T2 gets released. According to my if statement for T2 I have `26 % (3 + 10) == 0` .

```
void prvTaskSchedulerProcess(void *pvParameters) {

...

uint32_t uCurrentTickCount = 0;
gll_t* pTaskList = (gll_t*) pvParameters;
WorkerTask_t* pWorkerTask = NULL;

while (true) {

    for (uint8_t uIndex = 0; uIndex < pTaskList->size; uIndex++) {

        pWorkerTask = gll_get(pTaskList, uIndex);

        // Check if the task is ready to be executed
        if ( (uCurrentTickCount % (pWorkerTask->uReleaseTime + pWorkerTask->uPeriod) ) == 0) ){

            // Dispatch the ready task
            vTaskResume(pWorkerTask->xHandle); 
        }
    }

    uCurrentTickCount++;
    // Sleep the scheduler task, so the other tasks can run
    vTaskDelay(TASK_SCHEDULER_TICK_TIME * SCHEDULER_OUTPUT_FREQUENCY_MS); 
}
}
```

Using extra flags seems like a simple solution. However I was told that introducing flags variables is not best solution, because it makes code less readable and maintainable. Thus, I want to avoid using them. How would the correct task dispatching be achieved without using the extra flags (possibly correcting my if statement condition)?

Comment: Your release times are not quite clear for me. Does it mean that the tasks are released just once at T1(t)=10,T2(t)=3,T3(t)=5,T4(t)=0? In that case T1 and T4 are not released at the same time. Or are they periodic tasks which are released with a periodicity of T1=[0,10,20,30..],T2=[0,3,6...],T3=[0,5,10,15...],
 T4=[here?] ?. In that case, when is T4 released?

Comment: @Jose All tasks are released periodically with the period of t = 10, however their release times differ. Release time of a task here means a time when the first job of the task is ready to be executed.
For example the task T2 has release time at t=3, so it cannot be released t < 3, once t = 3, it is executed periodically every 10 time units, e.g T2 = {3, 13, 23, 33, ...}. 
Similarly, job's of other tasks become ready for the execution at: T1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, ...}, T3 = {5, 15, 25, 35, ...}, T4 = {0, 10, 20, 30, ...}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix problem 2, use the following condition instead of what you have.

```
if ((uCurrentTickCount % pWorkerTask->uPeriod) == pWorkerTask->uReleaseTime)
```

To fix problem 1 (and problem 2), use the following condition.

```
if ((uCurrentTickCount >= pWorkerTask->uReleaseTime) &&
    ((uCurrentTickCount % pWorkerTask->uPeriod) == (pWorkerTask->uReleaseTime % pWorker->uPeriod)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note using vTaskResume() in this way in inherently dangerous if there is even the tiniest little chance that the task you are resuming has not finished its previous actions and suspended itself again.  See the API docs for a fuller explanation https://www.freertos.org/taskresumefromisr.html

Comment: I was suspending tasks using `vTaskSuspend ` inside other tasks, and resuming them using function `vTaskResume ` from the task dispatcher which is just another task with the highest priority in my case. So do I need to check manually in my code whether the task has been already suspended? For example:

`eTaskState currentTaskState = eTaskGetState(pHighestPrirorityTaskBlockedBySemaphore->xHandle);

if (currentTaskState != eRunning)
{
 vTaskResume(pWorkerTask->xHandle);
}                                           
`